# How to copy a full collection in Meteor to another collection?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How do you copy a full collection in Meteor to another collection? Let use say: how do we copy all records in bulk from collection `planTmp` to `plan`.

I know about MongoDB's methods like e.g: [`copyTo`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/), but these cannot be used directly from Meteor on the server side.

I was just wondering how you can do it in Meteor with a reasonable performance.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution, but I am not sure, if this is the best one to copy one table to another fully:

```
PlanTemp.rawCollection().find().toArray()
    .then(result => Plan.rawCollection().insertMany(result))
    .then(() => {
        console.log('All plan time data copied');
    });
```